initMap no es función
Estoy usando el distance matrix para saber la distancia de un punto a otro con javascript.
estoy usando este código, pero me sale este error.


function initMap() {
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  const request = {
    origins: ["san andres,tlalpan"],
    destinations: ["parres,tlapan"],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
  };

  service.getDistanceMatrix(request).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
   
  });
}
 <script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=miapi&callback=initMap">
</script>




Estás segura de que tu API Key es válida?

Si. Ya la probé con fetch pero no puedo imprimir en consola solo la distancia me dice que es null. Por eso estoy intentando con esta forma
